# Openshift node not showing up on oo-mco ping

Tags: openshift-origin, mcollective

I've installed Openshift Origin as described in [the comprehensive guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html#the-node-host) on a single box (all in one setup). The problem is, that I can't add my node to a district, therefore it's not possible to use Openshift on that machine.

When I type

```
oo-admin-ctl-district -c add-node -n Default -i node.example.com
```

I get

```
/usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-district:215:in 'block in <main>': undefined method 'casecmp' f  or nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-district:178:in `block in collate_errors'
from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-district:176:in `each'
from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-district:176:in `collate_errors'
from /usr/sbin/oo-admin-ctl-district:213:in `<main>'
```

I tried to pin the problem down, an I think it's because the node doesn't connect to the message queue correctly as `oo-mco ping` gives me

```
broker.example.com                       time=94.30 ms


---- ping statistics ----
1 replies max: 94.30 min: 94.30 avg: 94.30
```

I checked my config with the comprehensive guide several times, but couldn't find any problem yet. Any help or tipps on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what I am actually doing, but this post did solve my problem so far

http://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/dev/2014-September/msg00087.html

Seems that I had the same issue, and that Openshift Origin comprehensive Depoyment guide needs an update.